# Is it possible to execute two Scapy commands at the same time in a Python script

Tags: python, scapy

I want to execute two Scapy commands simultaneously in a Python file, e.g: send(IP(dst="x.x.x.x") and sniff(). The problem I am trying to resolve is that when the script begin sniffing (on a server side) , the packet (from client) is already received before the beginning of sniff().
Is it possible to run two commands at the same time ? Thanks

Comment: Use two threads. Done. ;)

Comment: You have two different machines you are using for this or it is on the same machine?

Comment: For a good question regarding threading problems and Scapy, see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279661/scapy-fails-to-sniff-packets-when-using-multiple-threads

Comment: I am using two virtual machines

Comment: Have you looked at the `sr1()` function?